# Segmentation fault core dumped when reading file

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fgets

I got segmentation fault (core dumped) error in line 24 (fgets). I'm not very familliar with c, but I had to make a program for my classes. I have following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
   FILE *fd1, *fd2;
   char *str1, *str2;
   char *salt, *hash, *key, *key1;
   char buf[13], word[200], pass[200];

   if(argc != 2){
       fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <file shadow>\n", argv[0]);
       exit(1);
   }

   str1 = (char*) malloc(100);
   str2 = (char*) malloc(100);

   fd1 = fopen(argv[1], "r");

   fprintf(stderr, "Please, wait...\n");

   while(fgets(str1, 100, fd1) != NULL){
       str2 = strstr(str1, "$1$");
       if(str2 != NULL){
           key = strtok(str2, ":");
           snprintf(pass, sizeof(pass), "%s", key);
           printf("pass=%s (%lu)\n", pass, strlen(pass));

           strtok(key, "$");
           salt = strtok(NULL, "$");
           hash = strtok(NULL, "\0");

           snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "$1$%s$", salt);

           fd2 = fopen("polish.txt", "r");

           while(fgets(word, 200, fd2) != NULL){
               (&word[strlen(word)])[-1] = '\0';

           key1 = crypt(word, buf);

           if(!strncmp(key1, pass, strlen(key1))){
               printf("OK!, The password is: %s\n\n", word);
               break;
           }


           }
       }

   }
   fclose(fd1);
   fclose(fd2);
   free(str1);
   free(str2);

   return 0;
 }
```

When I try to read a /etc/shadow file it throws me segmentation fault (tried with custom txt file too). Could anyone take a look at this?

Comment: What debugging have you done? Where does it crash? If you do not know how to read a core dump with a debugger, then that is something you should learn so you can debug this sort of problem.

Comment: He is on such an ancient unix system where debugging is still considered to be only for the weak ;)

Comment: Minor: Why use `"%lu"` instead of `"%u"` or the correct `"%zu"`?

Comment: 1) magic numbers (in this case 100 and 200) are a maintenance nightmare.  suggest using #define for each number and replacing the hardcoded magic numbers with the #define name(s).  2) always check the returned value from strtok to assure operation successful. 3) always check the returned value from fopen() to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: suggest declaring local variables one(1) per line, with an initial value and a comment, so (later on) you and (right now) me know what the variables are used for.  such comments greatly help when someone(me) is trying to reverse engineer your code to try to help you

Comment: which line throws the seg fault event?

Answer (score 3):

There are couple of things you can improve in your code,

1. You don't need to **cast** `malloc`, it's not needed and may lead to untrackable bugs.
2. You don't need to **use** `malloc` for a local variable of fixed size.
3. You never check for the return value of any of the functions which return `NULL` on failure, in your case these:

   1. `malloc()`
   2. `fopen()`
   3. `strok()`

all these functions return `NULL` on failure.

4. You `malloc` and assing the pointer `str2`, but then you overwrite it at

   ```
    str2 = strstr(str1, "$1$");
   ```

there is no point in doing that, it means that you don't understand how pointers work. `strstr()` returns a pointer to the same string passed to it, just incremented to point to the begining of the substring you are looking for, or `NULL` if it wasn't found.

5. You have

   ```
    key = strtok(str2, ":");
    /* some other code */
    strtok(key, "$");
   ```

that's wrong because you are passing an incremented pointer to the same string, you must do it this way, read [`strtok()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html)

```
    strtok(NULL, "$");
```

6. You `fclose` the `fd2` I/O stream outside the `while` loop, but you `fopen()` it inside, you might have `fopen`ed it many more times than those you `fclose`d it.

You have two options, either you move the `fclose()` inside the `while` loop, or you move the `fopen()` outside the `while` loop, the second one is of course, better.

So as you see, you have a lot of potential undefined behavior, particularily, dereferencing a `NULL` pointer in your code, you should fix all these things if you want to prevent a `SEGMENTATION FAULT`.

It's fairly common to see programmers ignore these things, but you should make sure your program wont crash, by just being careful.

- Check for every pointer dereferenced unless it's very evident that it will not be `NULL`.
- Make every pointer `NULL` at declaration or right after it, that way you can insure that if it's not pointing to anything yet, then it's `NULL`, and you can check against that.

Handling pointers is a very difficult thing to get right, but once you develop these good habits, you will never have silly bugs again -> *well, almost never*!

Comment: Why on earth would you need to say "from the many errors on your code"

Comment: I don't think it is rude to point this out. I was just being direct. Please feel free to edit that part. Although, I relly think there's nothing wrong with saying that, I understand that it can be taken as a rude comment.

Comment: I updated the answer. So you can now remove this comment and I'll remove mine too.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is a lack of error checking on this line:

```
 fd1 = fopen(argv[1], "r");
```

`fopen()` [returns](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/) either a pointer to a populated `FILE` object, or `NULL` if it fails to open the file (either the file doesn't exist, or the user in insufficiently privileged to read it).

As a result a `NULL` pointer is passed into the call to `fgets()` on line 24.

You should check it for NULL:

```
fd1 = fopen(argv[1], "r");
if (fd1 == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open file for reading\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

Where we're on the subject of NULL pointers, you should also check the calls to `malloc()` too.  These are less likely to fail, but could also be responsible for the crash on line 24.

Comment: And the result of the calls to `strtok`

Answer (score 1):

C doesn't have exception mechanism like Java. Only way to get information about error it to check value returned from function and sometimes to get more info `errno`.

In your code you should check if `fopen` succeed and if not exit with error information.

Your program crashed because you probably try to read file which you don't have read permission and due to `fopen` return `NULL`. Hotfix for it is to run program as root or with `sudo`.

**EDIT**

I tried it and your program crashed on:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   _IO_fgets (buf=0x7fffffffd6a0 "", n=200, fp=0x0) at iofgets.c:50 50   iofgets.c: No such file or directory.

because I don't have *polish.txt* when I added it, runs smoothly with no errors

Answer (score 0):

```
// always check returned values from system I/O functions
// always enable all warnings so problems are addressed
// do not use 'magic' numbers
// initialize local variables that are pointers
//   (and generally all local variables)
// when an error is encountered during execution,
//    then release allocated memory, close files before exiting
// always look for and handle errors during execution

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <crypt.h> // <-- added for crypt() function

#define MAX_WORD_LEN (200)
#define MAX_STR_LEN  (100)
#define MAX_BUF_LEN  (13)

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE *fd1 = NULL;
    FILE *fd2 = NULL;

    char *str1 = NULL;
    char *str2 = NULL;

    char *salt, *hash, *key, *key1;

    char buf[MAX_BUF_LEN]   = {'\0'};
    char word[MAX_WORD_LEN] = {'\0'};
    char pass[MAX_WORD_LEN] = {'\0'};

    if(argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <file shadow>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    // implied else, command line parameter count correct

    if( NULL == (str1 = malloc(MAX_STR_LEN) ))
    { // then, malloc failed
        perror( "malloc for str1 failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    if( NULL == (str2 = malloc(MAX_STR_LEN) ))
    { // then, malloc failed
        perror( "malloc for str2 failed" );
        free( str1 ); // cleanup
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    if( NULL == (fd1 = fopen(argv[1], "r") ) )
    { // then fopen failed
        perror( "fopen for parameter file name failed" );
        free( str1 ); // cleanup
        free( str2 );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    fprintf(stderr, "Please, wait...\n");

    while( fgets(str1, MAX_STR_LEN, fd1) )
    {
        if( NULL == (str2 = strstr(str1, "$1$") ) )
        { // then, strstr failed
            perror( "strstr for $1$ failed" );
            continue;
        }

        // implied else, strstr successful

        if( NULL != (key = strtok(str2, ":") ) )
        { // then, strtok failed
            perror( "strtok for : failed" );
            continue;
        }

        // implied else, strtok successful

        snprintf(pass, sizeof(pass), "%s", key);
        printf("pass=%s (%lu)\n", pass, strlen(pass));

        if( NULL == strtok(key, "$") )
        { // then strtok failed
            perror( "strtok for $ failed" );
            continue;
        }

        // implied else, strtok successful

        if( NULL == (salt = strtok(NULL, "$") ) )
        { // then strtok failed
            perror( "strtok for salt failed" );
            continue;
        }

        // implied else, strtok successful

        if( NULL == (hash = strtok(NULL, "\0") ) )
        { // then strtok failed
            perror( "strtok for hash failed" );
            continue;
        }

        // implied else, strtok successful

        snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "$1$%s$", salt);

        if( NULL == (fd2 = fopen("polish.txt", "r") ) )
        { // then fopen failed
            perror( "fopen for polish.txt failed" );
            fclose(fd1); // cleanup
            free(str1);
            free(str2);
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, fopen successful

        while( fgets(word, MAX_WORD_LEN, fd2) )
        {
            (&word[strlen(word)])[-1] = '\0'; // what last char is being dropped?

            key1 = crypt(word, buf);

            if(!strncmp(key1, pass, strlen(key1)))
            {
                printf("OK!, The password is: %s\n\n", word);
                break;
            }

            else
            {
                printf("Oh No, The password did not match\n\n");
            } // end if
        } // end while

        // prep for next test sequence
        fclose( fd2 );
        fd2 = NULL;
    } // end while

    fclose(fd1);
    fclose(fd2);

    free(str1);
    free(str2);

    return 0;
} // end function: main
```